# Should we allow tags of specific PM tools?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I've noticed a "redmine" tag showed up this week. Is this usefull? Will we have a specific tag for every PM tool out there?

Answer (score 5):

I think that we should allow tags for PM software (not least because so many questions are about MS Project!) but I'm not convinced we need one for each and every version. For example, we have tags for ms-project, ms-project-2013, ms-project-2010, ms-project-2007 and project-server (the last of which should really be renamed 'ms-project-server' if it's going to remain).

I'd suggest that where significant differences exist (like between MS Project Server and MS Project) then two different tags can exist. Otherwise they should be merged.

Comment: We could merge those tags if necessary for the MS Project questions or make them synonyms of the main MSProject tag.  As for tagging questions related to specific tools, my only question is could it encourage more spam?  Should we limit these to only very well known and widely used tools?

Comment: Limiting to widely used tools would be sensible I think. MS Project and JIRA seem to raise a lot of questions but I can't think of others that I come across regularly. The danger is, as you say, that the site gets overwhelmed by Q&As for these products. Atlassian have Answers (https://answers.atlassian.com) for this so maybe we should be redirecting the specific stuff there?

Comment: In response to [@Willl's comment](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/115/should-we-allow-tags-of-specific-pm-tools#comment1190_734): I think the line between "using tools in a PM context" and "product support" is a slippery slope. The former is generally on-topic, the latter much less so; it's a slippery slope. I don't think we can make a sweeping generalization at this time without precluding legitimate tool-related questions altogether.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there should be a "pm-software" tag, but I also think it's okay to have specific tags for each tool.

For instance, on Stack Overflow, there is a tag for Java, but there is also a tag for Spring, which is a Java Framework.  There is a tag for JavaScript, and there is a tag for JQuery.

Each question can have up to 5 tags, so we have plenty of room to grow and break things down.

Comment: @stephan, It's also useful when you want to filter your search results to a specific subject. E.g. searching for [redmine] would bring me only questions tagged with the redmine tag.