# Planned Tag Blacklist Request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist

Instead of removing all of the tags identified in [my answer to this meta post](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/408/34), I'm considering putting in a tag burn and blacklist request to remove the following tags completely from our site:

- [common-project-problems](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-project-problems)
- [best-practices](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices)
- [project-manager](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-manager)
- [project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project)

These are the worst of the worst when it comes to tags. Every question could arguably be about a project management problem. It's why people come see us. Best practices are really what everyone strives for, and project manager and project are very "meta", as the site is *about* project management.

I plan to submit the blacklist request to Stack Exchange by next Wednesday, September 18th, so if anyone wants to go through these tags and edit any of the questions or retag them, this is a good opportunity to do so.  When Stack Exchange blacklists a tag, the tag is removed from all questions, and questions where that was the only tag get a special [untagged](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, until someone retags the question.

Comment: I agree. However I have doubts about [tag:common-project-problems]. It has many questions tagged under it (I know this is not a valid reason). Also, what tag(s) to use for posts like [What are the biggest mistakes that new project managers make](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/92/what-are-the-biggest-mistakes-that-new-project-managers-make)?

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Your question is sort of why I wanted to go through all the questions. That particular example needs to be closed (not deleted, just closed). We don't want to compile a list of mistakes in one massive post; instead, we want thousands of laser-focused questions that each focus on a different problem because that's what draws experts. Biggest mistakes is sort of a place for the inexperienced or mildly curious to hang out. It's not an example of a good, on-topic question for our site.

Comment: And think about "common project problems". What *is* a common problem? How does one tell the difference between that and an *uncommon* problem? I've stared at this tag for a long time and still can't tell you what that tag is actually about. We can definitely do a better job retagging the 102 questions that currently hold that meta tag. Please see [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for more details. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

Okay. That .. took a hot second, but it's done. Those tags have been destroyed, and blacklisted along with their plurals. I've also added the intrinsic tag blacklist for [project-management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management), which was missing, but thankfully not problematic.

This resulted in [more than a few untagged questions](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), some of which look pretty smelly, so please have a peek at them and re-tag what's valuable while disposing of what isn't.

Thanks for keeping the place clean!

Answer (score 2):

I'm in favor of purging those tags as being "too meta." This morning, I took a stab at removing/replacing [best-practices](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) from a number of posts, but it's not a trivial exercise.

I have no objection to having the SE administrators simply purge the tags, but we also have the ability as a community to retag them as we go. The first is easier on us, obviously, but we still have a path forward if they say "no."

Please *do* submit the request, and let us know how it goes. In the meantime, I will continue to retag as time and energy permit.

Comment: I lost track of this. Thanks for bringing it back up.

Comment: Do you think it's possible for our community to deprecate these tags, as in if we see folks trying to use them we proactively remove them? The common problems tag keeps getting added to new posts. Also, Jeff suggests we [start from the bottom, the worst of the worst, deal with them, then remove the tags en-masse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).