# Should we have specific tags for VSTS and and TFS or we should keep a single one?

Tags: discussion

This question comes from [Remaining Work rollup issue](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/21043/430).

Based on the premises that we are ok on having [software-specific tags](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/should-we-allow-tags-of-specific-pm-tools), should we have tags for Visual Studio Team System (VSTS) and Team Foundation Server (TFS)?

I don't have much experience with either of them, but I understand they're slightly different tools, which would support the idea of specific tags.

OTOH, there isn't much questions around for VSTS / TFS in our community, so having different tags could be overkill... but then, how this common tag would be called? Microsoft Team Tools? It could cause further confusion with MS Project (which is pretty consolidated).

Thoughts?

Comment: Off the cuff, I don't see the need to merge them so long as they're different tools. The trick is just making sure the tool-related questions are on topic, regardless of which tool. I'd let it be for now; where's the harm?

Answer (score 1):

If we take future-proofing into account, then I don't think the current number of questions is relevant. We'd do better to choose a criteria and then stick to it, rather than cherry-picking different scenarios. Which leaves us with two options:

1. Pick all technologies that are *sufficiently similar*, comparable to VSTS and TFS, and combine them. This could plausibly include MS Project; it would certainly include folding all the different ms-project-version tags into one.
2. Pick all technologies that are *sufficiently different*, comparable to VSTS and TFS, and split them.

Of the two, I believe 2 is what we're currently doing, and thus requires the least effort and will make fewer waves.